# jQuery get each images width then add css width to each images

Tags: jquery, width

I would like to know how can I get each images widths (many widths) in different li then give that width back to each images via jQuery.

All images have different widths.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').each(function() {

  var width = $(this).width();

   // OR

  var width = this.clientWidth;

  // to set that width to image try

  $(this).attr('width', width);

   // according to comment: how to assign width to parent li

   $(this).parent('li').css('width', width + 'px');
});
```

Comment: I try this:

`$('#myGallery img').each(function() {
  $(this).css('width', this.width);
});`

and it works it gives all my images their width but how can I give that width to the parent li ...

Comment: @user2084110 welcome and best way to thank is upvote and accept the answer :)